# Using an Argument in a Stored Procedure to Name a Temp Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a stored procedure in Redshift that outputs a temporary table containing a player name and their score:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_sp1(f1 int, f2 varchar(20))
AS $$
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_tbl;
  CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_tbl(score int, player varchar(15));
  INSERT INTO tmp_tbl values (f1, f2);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

call test_sp1(5, 'james');

select * from tmp_tbl;
```

However, I would like the stored procedure to create a temporary table with the suffix of f2, a long the lines of:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_sp1(f1 int, f2 varchar(20))
AS $$
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_tbl_{f2};
  CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_tbl_{f2}(score int, player varchar(15));
  INSERT INTO tmp_tbl_{f2} values (f1, f2);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

call test_sp1(5, 'james');

select * from tmp_tbl_james;
```

Is this something that is possible?

Comment: This `tmp_tbl_{f2}` is not going to work. To see what will work read [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).